# How does Distinct() function work in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, distinct

I'm a newbie to Apache Spark and was learning basic functionalities.
Had a small doubt.Suppose I have an RDD of tuples (key, value) and wanted to obtain some unique ones out of them. I use distinct() function. I'm wondering on what basis does the function consider that tuples as disparate..? Is it based on the keys, or values, or both?

Answer (score 28):

`.distinct()` is definitely doing a shuffle across partitions.  To see more of what's happening, run a `.toDebugString` on your RDD.

```
val hashPart = new HashPartitioner(<number of partitions>)

val myRDDPreStep = <load some RDD>

val myRDD = myRDDPreStep.distinct.partitionBy(hashPart).setName("myRDD").persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
myRDD.checkpoint
println(myRDD.toDebugString)
```

which for an RDD example I have (myRDDPreStep is already hash-partitioned by key, persisted by StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, and checkpointed), returns:

```
(2568) myRDD ShuffledRDD[11] at partitionBy at mycode.scala:223 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
+-(2568) MapPartitionsRDD[10] at distinct at mycode.scala:223 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
    |    ShuffledRDD[9] at distinct at mycode.scala:223 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
    +-(2568) MapPartitionsRDD[8] at distinct at mycode.scala:223 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
        |    myRDDPreStep ShuffledRDD[6] at partitionBy at mycode.scala:193 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
        |        CachedPartitions: 2568; MemorySize: 362.4 GB; TachyonSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B
        |    myRDD[7] at count at mycode.scala:214 [Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated]
```

Note that there may be more efficient ways to get distinct that involve fewer shuffles, ESPECIALLY if your RDD is already partitioned in a smart way and the partitions are not overly skewed.

See [Is there a way to rewrite Spark RDD distinct to use mapPartitions instead of distinct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082066/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-spark-rdd-distinct-to-use-mappartitions-instead-of-di)
and
[Apache Spark: What is the equivalent implementation of RDD.groupByKey() using RDD.aggregateByKey()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081563/apache-spark-what-is-the-equivalent-implementation-of-rdd-groupbykey-using-rd)

Answer (score 15):

The API docs for [RDD.distinct()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) only provide a one sentence description:

> "Return a new RDD containing the distinct elements in this RDD."

From recent experience I can tell you that in a tuple-RDD the tuple as a whole is considered.

If you want distinct keys or distinct values, then depending on exactly what you want to accomplish, you can either:

A. call `groupByKey()` to transform `{(k1,v11),(k1,v12),(k2,v21),(k2,v22)}` to `{(k1,[v11,v12]), (k2,[v21,v22])}` ; or

B. strip out either the keys or values by calling `keys()` or `values()` followed by `distinct()`

As of this writing (June 2015) UC Berkeley + EdX is running a free online course [Introduction to Big Data and Apache Spark](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x) which would provide hands on practice with these functions.

Comment: Hi Paul! Let me suppose that we have an RDD tuple as follows: 
(1,20), (1,21), (1,20), (2,20), (2,22), (2,20), (3,21), (3,22)..etc.,
Here you could observe that both the keys and values are repeating in various tuples.
so if I apply distinct() on the above RDD, what would be the result..?
Please take a moment. Thank you!

And, yes I was taking that course online! :)

Comment: I don't have time right now but you can set up your own RDD with `myRDD = sc.parallelize([ (1,20), (1,21), (1,20), (2,20), (2,22), (2,20), (3,21), (3,22) ]);`  This may even work in one of the previous Lab notebooks from the Spark course.  Then run `myRDD.distinct().collect() to test the output`

Answer (score 12):

Justin Pihony is right. Distinct uses the hashCode and equals method of the objects for this determination. It's return the distinct elements(object)

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,20), (1,21), (1,20), (2,20), (2,22), (2,20), (3,21), (3,22)))
```

Distinct

```
rdd.distinct.collect().foreach(println)
(2,22)
(1,20)
(3,22)
(2,20)
(1,21)
(3,21)
```

If you want to apply distinct on key. 
In that case reduce by is better option

ReduceBy

```
 val reduceRDD= rdd.map(tup =>
    (tup._1, tup)).reduceByKey { case (a, b) => a }.map(_._2)

reduceRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

Output:-

```
(2,20)
(1,20)
(3,21)
```

Answer (score 9):

`distinct` uses the `hashCode` and `equals` method of the objects for this determination. Tuples come built in with the equality mechanisms delegating down into the equality and position of each object. So, `distinct` will work against the entire `Tuple2` object. As Paul pointed out, you can call `keys` or `values` and then `distinct`. Or you can write your own distinct values via `aggregateByKey`, which would keep the key pairing.  Or if you want the distinct keys, then you could use a regular `aggregate`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `distinct` will get rid of (key, value) duplicates.

In the below example (1,20) and (2,20) are repeated twice in `myRDD`, but after a `distinct()`, the duplicates are removed.

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(List((1,20), (1,21), (1,20), (2,20), (2,22), (2,20), (3,21), (3,22)))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1274] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> myRDD.collect().foreach(println _)
(1,20)
(1,21)
(1,20)
(2,20)
(2,22)
(2,20)
(3,21)
(3,22)

scala> myRDD.distinct.collect().foreach(println _)
(2,22)
(1,20)
(3,22)
(2,20)
(1,21)
(3,21)
```