# Apache Spark: What is the equivalent implementation of RDD.groupByKey() using RDD.aggregateByKey()?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

The Apache Spark `pyspark.RDD` API docs mention that `groupByKey()` is inefficient.  Instead, it is recommend to use `reduceByKey()`, `aggregateByKey()`, `combineByKey()`, or `foldByKey()` instead.  This will result in doing some of the aggregation in the workers prior to the shuffle, thus reducing shuffling of data across workers.

Given the following data set and `groupByKey()` expression, what is an equivalent and efficient implementation (reduced cross-worker data shuffling) that does not utilize `groupByKey()`, but delivers the same result?

```py
dataset = [("a", 7), ("b", 3), ("a", 8)]
rdd = (sc.parallelize(dataset)
       .groupByKey())
print sorted(rdd.mapValues(list).collect())
```

Output:

```
[('a', [7, 8]), ('b', [3])]
```

Comment: Is your data partitioned randomly, or by key?  If you can ensure that all records with a._1 = "a" are on the same partition, you can speed up things dramatically -- you may be able to get away without needing any shuffles, other than the ones needed for the initial partitioning.  Maybe try using a hash partitioner?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is nothing to gain* in this particular case by using `aggregateByKey` or a similar function. Since you're building a list there is no "real" reduction and amount of data which has to be shuffled is more or less the same.

To really observe some performance gain you need transformations which actually reduces amount of the transfered data for example counting, computing summary statistics, finding unique elements.

Regarding differences benefits of using `reduceByKey()`, `combineByKey()`, or `foldByKey()` there is an important conceptual difference which is easier to see when you consider Scala API singatures.

Both `reduceByKey` and `foldByKey` map from `RDD[(K, V)]` to `RDD[(K, V)]` while the second one provides additional zero element.

```scala
reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)] 
foldByKey(zeroValue: V)(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

`combineByKey` (there is no `aggregateByKey`, but it is the same type of transformation) transforms from `RDD[(K, V)]` to `RDD[(K, C)]`:

```py
combineByKey[C](
   createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C,
   mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C,
   mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

Going back to your example only `combineByKey` (and in PySpark `aggregateByKey`) is really applicable since you are transforming from `RDD[(String, Int)]` to `RDD[(String, List[Int])]`.

While in a dynamic language like Python it is actually possible to perform such an operation using `foldByKey` or `reduceByKey` it makes semantics of the code unclear and to cite @tim-peters *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it*" [1].

Difference between `aggregateByKey` and `combineByKey` is pretty much the same as between `reduceByKey` and `foldByKey` so for a list it is mostly a matter of taste:

```py
def merge_value(acc, x):
    acc.append(x)
    return acc

def merge_combiners(acc1, acc2):
    acc1.extend(acc2)
    return acc1

rdd = (sc.parallelize([("a", 7), ("b", 3), ("a", 8)])
   .combineByKey(
       lambda x: [x],
       lambda u, v: u + [v],
       lambda u1,u2: u1+u2))
```

In practice you should prefer `groupByKey` though. PySpark implementation is significantly more optimized compared to naive implementation like the one provided above.

1.Peters, T. PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python. (2004). at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

---

* In practice there is actually quite a lot to loose here, especially when using PySpark. Python implementation of `groupByKey` is significantly more optimized than naive combine by key. You can check [Be Smart About groupByKey](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey), created by me and [@eliasah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah) for an additional discussion.

Comment: If you use a partitioner (say, partition by a hash of the key), can you get away without needing any other shuffles?

Comment: @GlennStrycker As far as I know the answer is positive. If RDD is partitioned by key then all values for a given key should be processed locally on a single node. Possible problem is a skewed distribution of keys though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option that uses `aggregateByKey()`.  I'd be curious to hear how this can be done using `reduceByKey()`, `combineByKey()`, or `foldByKey()`, and what cost/benefit there is to each alternative.

```
rdd = (sc.parallelize([("a", 7), ("b", 3), ("a", 8)])
       .aggregateByKey(list(),
                       lambda u,v: u+[v],
                       lambda u1,u2: u1+u2))
print sorted(rdd.mapValues(list).collect())
```

Output:

```
[('a', [7, 8]), ('b', [3])]
```

The following is a slightly more memory efficient implementation, though less readable to the python novice, which produces the same output:

```
rdd = (sc.parallelize([("a", 7), ("b", 3), ("a", 8)])
       .aggregateByKey(list(),
                       lambda u,v: itertools.chain(u,[v]),
                       lambda u1,u2: itertools.chain(u1,u2)))
print sorted(rdd.mapValues(list).collect())
```