# find the minimum and maximum date from the data in a RDD in PySpark

Tags: python, datetime, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using `Spark` with `Ipython` and have a `RDD` which contains data in this format when printed:

`print rdd1.collect()`

```
[u'2010-12-08 00:00:00', u'2010-12-18 01:20:00', u'2012-05-13 00:00:00',....]
```

Each data is a `datetimestamp` and I want to find the minimum and the maximum in this `RDD`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

You can for example use `aggregate` function (for an explanation how it works see: [What is the equivalent implementation of RDD.groupByKey() using RDD.aggregateByKey()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31081563/1560062))

```
from datetime import datetime    

rdd  = sc.parallelize([
    u'2010-12-08 00:00:00', u'2010-12-18 01:20:00', u'2012-05-13 00:00:00'])

def seq_op(acc, x):
    """ Given a tuple (min-so-far, max-so-far) and a date string
    return a tuple (min-including-current, max-including-current)
    """
    d = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return (min(d, acc[0]), max(d, acc[1]))

def comb_op(acc1, acc2):
    """ Given a pair of tuples (min-so-far, max-so-far)
    return a tuple (min-of-mins, max-of-maxs)
    """
    return (min(acc1[0], acc2[0]), max(acc1[1], acc2[1]))

# (initial-min <- max-date, initial-max <- min-date)
rdd.aggregate((datetime.max, datetime.min), seq_op, comb_op)

## (datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 13, 0, 0))
```

or `DataFrames`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, min, max

row = Row("ts")
df = rdd.map(row).toDF()

df.withColumn("ts", unix_timestamp("ts")).agg(
    from_unixtime(min("ts")).alias("min_ts"), 
    from_unixtime(max("ts")).alias("max_ts")
).show()

## +-------------------+-------------------+
## |             min_ts|             max_ts|
## +-------------------+-------------------+
## |2010-12-08 00:00:00|2012-05-13 00:00:00|
## +-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: is it possible if you could mention some comments about how is the code working (the two functions especially) so that I am able to understand it properly?

Answer (score 3):

If you RDD consists of datetime objects, what is wrong with simply using

```
rdd1.min()
rdd1.max()
```

See [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

This example works for me

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([u'2010-12-08 00:00:00', u'2010-12-18 01:20:00', u'2012-05-13 00:00:00'])
from datetime import datetime
rddT = rdd.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).cache()
print rddT.min()
print rddT.max()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dataframes you don't need nothing but this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
#Anohter imports, session, attributions etc
# This brings min and max(considering you need only min and max values)
df.select(F.min('datetime_column_name'),F.max('datetime_column_name')).show()
```

and that's it!

Comment: It is simple and worked for me! Thank you