# Can any one implement CombineByKey() instead of GroupByKey() in Spark in order to group elements?

Tags: apache-spark

i am trying to group elements of an RDD that i have created. one simple but expensive way is to use `GroupByKey()`. but recently i learned that `CombineByKey()` can do this work more efficiently. my RDD is very simple. it looks like this:

```
(1,5)
(1,8)
(1,40)
(2,9)
(2,20)
(2,6)
```

```
val grouped_elements=first_RDD.groupByKey()..mapValues(x => x.toList)
```

the result is:

```
(1,List(5,8,40))
(2,List(9,20,6))
```

i want to group them based on the first element (key).

can any one help me to do it with `CombineByKey()` function? i am really confused by `CombineByKey()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Spark: What is the equivalent implementation of RDD.groupByKey() using RDD.aggregateByKey()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081563/apache-spark-what-is-the-equivalent-implementation-of-rdd-groupbykey-using-rd)

Comment: it is some thing near to my question. but not exactly what i want. but thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with take a look at API Refer [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html)

```
combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

So it accepts three functions which I have defined below

```
scala> val createCombiner = (v:Int) => List(v)
createCombiner: Int => List[Int] = <function1>

scala> val mergeValue = (a:List[Int], b:Int) => a.::(b)
mergeValue: (List[Int], Int) => List[Int] = <function2>

scala> val mergeCombiners = (a:List[Int],b:List[Int]) => a.++(b)
mergeCombiners: (List[Int], List[Int]) => List[Int] = <function2>
```

Once you define these then you can use it in your combineByKey call as below

```
scala> val list = List((1,5),(1,8),(1,40),(2,9),(2,20),(2,6))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,5), (1,8), (1,40), (2,9), (2,20), (2,6))

scala> val temp = sc.parallelize(list)
temp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[41] at parallelize at <console>:30

scala> temp.combineByKey(createCombiner,mergeValue, mergeCombiners).collect
res27: Array[(Int, List[Int])] = Array((1,List(8, 40, 5)), (2,List(20, 9, 6)))
```

Please note that I tried this out in Spark Shell and hence you can see the outputs below the commands executed. They will help build you your understanding.