# Getting first n distinct Key Tuples in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

I have a RDD with Tuple as follows

```
(a, 1), (a, 2), (b,1)
```

How can I can get the first two tuples with **distinct** keys. If I do a take(2), I will get (a, 1) and (a, 2)

What I need is (a, 1), (b,1) (Keys are distinct). Values are irrelevant.

Comment: The example at the bottom of this post should help.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30960114/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 distinct will compare the entire tuple. What i need to compare is just the key for the tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I threw together in Scala.

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1)))
    .reduceByKey((k1,k2) => k1)
    .collect()
```

Outputs

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,1))
```

Comment: Can be simplified - `reduceByKey` can be called on the original tuple RDD, then you won't need the map at the beginning and end: `input.reduceByKey((k1,k2) => k1).take(2)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a `RDD` of `Pair`, your `RDD` has extra key-value functionality provided by `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions`. Lets make use of that.

```
val pairRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1)))
// RDD[(String, Int)]

val groupedRdd = pairRdd.groupByKey()
// RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])]

val requiredRdd = groupedRdd.map((key, iter) => (key, iter.head))
// RDD[(String, Int)]
```

Or in short

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1)))
  .groupByKey()
  .map((key, iter) => (key, iter.head))
```

Answer (score -2):

It is easy.....
you just need to use the function just like the bellow:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1)))
data.collectAsMap().foreach(println)
```

Comment: If it's an RDD, the collectAsMap may well blow up as the data won't fit on one node. If it fits, there would be no need to use Spark

Comment: I do not get what result you really need,if you just want to get the distinct key and ignore the value,there are already anwsers in the commemts