# spark job get only one result for one key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I now have a lot of key value pairs (key, value)

Now for one key, I don't want to get the value's average or some other aggregations, I just need one value. (Get the distinct keys)

Let me have an example here,

```
("1","apple")
("1","apple")
("2","orange")
("2","orange")
("1","apple")
("1","pear")
```

The result can be

```
("2","orange")
("1","apple")
```

or

```
("2","orange")
("1","pear")
```

I can use `reduceByKey(((a,b) => a))` to get this, but as there are a lot of keys, the time is very long.

Any one have some better suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want only `("2","orange") ("1","apple")` or any sample pairs?

Comment: I want the result contains all the keys, for keys having different values, just one sample value is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is a typical map-reduce like problem. But you just want only one value to each key, so simply you can do it in reduce phase, although it is not the best way. And now you know that using reduceByKey only will cost a lot of time in useless shuffle, which means you should pre-reduce your data in Mapper. So the answer is obvious for you: using combiner.

In spark you can use combineByKey before your reduceByKey to remove duplicate values.

==========

Besides combiner, you can also change the shuffle method. The default shuffle for Spark 1.2+ is SortShuffle. You can change it to HashShuffle which can reduce the cost of sorting keys.

try to set this in your sparkConf

```
spark.shuffle.manager = hash
spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles = true
```

But you have to pay attention that too much map cores may produce too much shuffle files which will affect the performance.`spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles` is used to merge mapper output files.

Comment: Thanks, but as I have a lot of keys, even combiner used, it would still take a lof of time in useless shuffle. I'm thinking about a hash map to use...but no idea..

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can try hash shuffle instead of using default sort shuffle. But you have to pay attention that too much map cores may produce too much shuffle files which will affect the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yiling, you may use the transformation *distinct* to keep distinct elements in your RDD. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Comment: Thanks! But it seems your distinct will only distinct the same element. For me, if I happened to have ("1","apple") and ("1","orange"), I only want one sample exist in the result.

Comment: ah, in this case distinct is not the right transformation to use. According to the dicussion [how-does-distinct-function-work-in-spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959955/how-does-distinct-function-work-in-spark), in a tuple-RDD the tuple as a whole is considered.

Comment: Hi, Yiling, if I'm not mistaken, you're actually asking for "distinct by key". Can you modify your question description? as I quote, " I assume the same key will have the same value", which is really misleading.

Comment: THanks U, I just modified my question

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dropDuplicates()` of DataFrame.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  List(
      ("1", "apple"),
      ("1", "apple"),
      ("2", "orange"),
      ("2", "orange"),
      ("1", "apple"),
      ("1", "pear")
  )
).toDF("count", "name")

df.show()
+-----+------+
|count|  name|
+-----+------+
|    1| apple|
|    1| apple|
|    2|orange|
|    2|orange|
|    1| apple|
|    1|  pear|
+-----+------+
```

drop duplicates by name

```
val uniqueDf = df.dropDuplicates("name")
```

Now pick top 2 unique rows

```
uniqueDf.limit(2).show()

+-----+------+
|count|  name|
+-----+------+
|    2|orange|
|    1| apple|
+-----+------+
```

Unique records without limit

```
uniqueDf.show()
+-----+------+
|count|  name|
+-----+------+
|    2|orange|
|    1| apple|
|    1|  pear|
+-----+------+
```

**Edit:**

You can use `collect()` on DataFrame to get values into List.