# Execution of Distinct operation on large data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

when we perform `distinct` operation in Spark on a delta table or s3/gcs data files, does it  pull entire data to single executor like `group by`?
What if a table has large amount of data, how do we handle such usecase if spark performs operation in single executor?

```
#sql 
select distinct <all columns> from table/dataframe

or

#pyspark
df.select("*").distinct()
```

Comment: Like a `group by`, it will _not_ collect all rows to one executor. Rather, Spark will use hash as a key to shuffle the data and eliminate dups.

Comment: got it. Just to make sure I follow, does Spark eliminates dups based on hash key on individual partition first and later brings inter partitions together into single partition for final distinct or Spark pulls all similar hashkeys(without performing initial distinct) to single partition and performs distinct only once?

Answer (score 1):

There are two major kind of actions in spark: Transformations and Actions.

Action will trigger a calculation at once and gather the result to local machine(suppose you're using spark-shell).

Transformations will generate a new dataset but not actually compute it unless you trigger a `Action`.

> All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute their results right away. Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program. This design enables Spark to run more efficiently. For example, we can realize that a dataset created through map will be used in a reduce and return only the result of the reduce to the driver, rather than the larger mapped dataset.

You can find that `distinct` is kind of `transformation` for [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

> distinct([numPartitions]))    Return a new dataset that contains the distinct elements of the source dataset.

So, for your first question, `distinct` won't gather all dataset to your driver machine.

It's not a good idea to collect data to driver if you are dealing with large dataset. A better way is to write the result to a distributed storage such as HDFS or S3.

---

update: since OP wants to know something about distinct implement detail rather than what I misunderstood former, I try to dig into the code:

```scala
  def distinct(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] = withScope {
    def removeDuplicatesInPartition(partition: Iterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
      // Create an instance of external append only map which ignores values.
      val map = new ExternalAppendOnlyMap[T, Null, Null](
        createCombiner = _ => null,
        mergeValue = (a, b) => a,
        mergeCombiners = (a, b) => a)
      map.insertAll(partition.map(_ -> null))
      map.iterator.map(_._1)
    }
    partitioner match {
      case Some(_) if numPartitions == partitions.length =>
        mapPartitions(removeDuplicatesInPartition, preservesPartitioning = true)
      case _ => map(x => (x, null)).reduceByKey((x, _) => x, numPartitions).map(_._1)
    }
  }
```

Spark will first deleive task by `Partitioner`.

To simplify the explanation of the problem, suppose we have a hash partitoner `h(x)` which will group data by first char, e.g:

- h("cat") = "c"
- h("car") = "c"
- h("book") = "b"

and the different data will be transfered to workers, "cat" and "car" to worker "c" and "book" to worker "b". And this is the driver's work.

Then on each worker node, they will distinct on local environment and return the result.

Back to your question, does distinct pulls **all data** to **single executor** to identify unique values. The answer is no, becausue each executor just responsible for handling the parts they should handle, and then driver just contact their result (if you call `collect` on dirver).

see also: [How does Distinct() function work in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959955/how-does-distinct-function-work-in-spark)

Comment: Though giving a good intuition of the answer, I think you're mixing up different concepts: lazyness of Spark (nothing happens until you call an "action" like `collect` or `write`), shuffling of data and executors/drivers.

Comment: @GaëlJ right, I understand action vs transformation. As you pointed out, I'm looking for how distinct on data is executed? does distinct pulls all data to single executor to identify unique values? thanks.

Comment: @user16798185 I have no idea. Best is to try and analyse on your own use case :) My guess (only a guess) is that distinct can happen on each executor and then an additional distinct on the individual result of each executor.

Comment: @counter2015 To conclude,is it fair understanding that distinct first happens at each (within) executor/partition-task level based on hash and later, final single distinct in a single executor/partition-task for all related groups(distinct columns) from all executor/partition-task? ie. Just to make sure I follow, does Spark eliminates dups based on hash key on individual partition first and later brings inter partitions together into single partition for final distinct or Spark pulls all similar hashkeys(without performing initial distinct) to single partition and performs distinct only once?